# Eventbridge and SQS fifo queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, fifo

I have added to our custom event bus a FIFO queue as a target.

When eventbridge is connected to a fifo queue the MessageGroupId property is required.

Is it possible to configure dynamically that value?

For example: I have a fifo queue where I put events from different users. Every event, inside the detail property, has a property uuid with the user identifier. 
I would like to use this property instead of e constant value as MessageGroupId. 
In this way, all events for the same user are going to be processed in the order.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible as of 4/8/2021.

The EventBridge input transformation puts the transformed payload into the `MessageBody` parameter of the SQS [SendMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html) API.

Any other API parameters cannot be modified from EventBridge.